# How to use more than one type of database in spring boot data jpa?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Actually, this question leads to the configuration of spring.jpa, and the Bean management of JpaProperties.

Usually, we use this configuration for postgresql:

```
 spring:
      jpa:
        database: default
        database-platform: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG9Dialect
        hibernate:
          ddl-auto: update
        properties:
          open-in-view: true
          hibernate:
            enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
      datasource:
        url: ...
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

But if i have a another mysql database, how to use them both?

Edit:
Actually, i used geo data in database, so `org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql`
or 
`org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG9Dialect` 
is used. 
I found it must be set in spring.jpa, so i think there must be two JpaProperties, but i don't know how to do that.
I tried

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.jpa.general")
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapterGeneral(){
    return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
}
```

with

```
spring:
  jpa:
    general:
      database-platform: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG9Dialect
```

but i failed.

Comment: @pvpkiran Thank you for formatting:)

Comment: if you have more than one data sources then you need to configure them yourself explicitly. spring boot default Auto configuration doesnt help. search for "configuring multiple datasources in springboot"

Comment: try following this tutorial https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

Comment: @RaulCuth Hi, thank you, but it does not fix my problem. I added  some  information, please help me.